# $state.go() not routing to other state, #/null in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angular ui-router I'm trying to use $state.go() to change to the blogEdit state after creating a new entry with blogCreate to continue editing after saving. When I click to save and trigger addPost() method, it doesnt redirect correctly and I see `/#/null` as the route in the address bar instead of the expected `/blog/post/:postId/edit`.

```
blogModule.controller('PostCreateController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'PostResource',
    function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, PostResource) {
        $scope.post = new PostResource();
        $scope.addPost = function () {
            $scope.post.$save(function () {
                $state.go('blogEdit', {postId: $stateParams.postId}); // THIS SHOULD REDIRECT TO CONTINUE EDITING POST
            });
        }
    }
]);

blogModule.controller('PostEditController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'PostResource',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, PostResource) {
        $scope.post = PostResource.get({postId: $stateParams.postId});
        $scope.updatePost = function () {
            $scope.post.$update({postId: $stateParams.postId});
        }
    }
]);
```

State route configuration:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'blogModule'
]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('blog', {
            url: '/blog',
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-list.html',
            controller: 'PostListController'
        })
        .state('blogView', {
            url: '/blog/post/{postId:[0-9]}',
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-detail.html',
            controller: 'PostViewController'
        })
        .state('blogCreate', {
            url: '/blog/post/new',
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-create.html',
            controller: 'PostCreateController'
        })
        .state('blogEdit', {
            url: '/blog/post/{postId:[0-9]}/edit',
            templateUrl: 'app/blog/view/blog-edit.html',
            controller: 'PostEditController'
        });
}]);
```

It seems to do this regardless of what state I try to change to.

Comment: What happens if you place breakpoint to the [$state.go] line? Do you see corrent values of $stateParam and its postId? Anyhow I dont see where are you getting the postId value from.

Comment: @svobol13 It is an empty object so that is probably the issue. Shoudl I save the response from $save() and get the id from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are saving your post on backend. When you perform save (`PUT`) operation your backend should return you some response. The response should be like `HTTP 201 Entity created` and there should be location attribute set (f.e. `http://example.com/blog/post/1`). Then you can get the id from location header like this:

```
$scope.post.$save(function (createdPost, headers) {
    var postId = headers.location.split("/").pop();
    $state.go('blogEdit', {postId: postId});
});
```

Another way is to just ignore headers and return json response from your backend. F.e. `{"postId": 1, "title": "New post", ...}`. Then you can do something like:

```
$scope.post.$save(function (createdPost) {
    $state.go('blogEdit', {postId: createdPost.postId});
});
```

The most important is to know API of your backend (what "it returns").